# Which EJB started the longest running transaction on JBoss?

Tags: jboss, monitoring

I work with JBoss 4.2.3 GA.

I'm looking for an easy way to monitor JBoss to understand problems with transactions and learn from real data how transactions work in general in JBoss. Questions I want to get answered are:

- What are the longest transactions running now?
- How long are they running?
- Which transaction has been suspended by which? Usually "nested" transaction suspend "parent" transaction.
- In which EJB each looooong/nested/parent transaction has started?

Support I found so far is not sufficient:

- **TransactionManager service** in JMX (console/twiddle) provides only general information like RunningTransactionCount,  TransactionTimeout, ApplicationRollbeckCount, etc.
- **ManagedConnectionPool service** in JMX and tools like **TOAD Oracle** (Session Browser) provide only DB-specific information, but do not tell which EJB started which looong transaction.